# API not displaying all parameters only some

Tags: javascript, api

```
 var nameval = data['name']
        var descrip = data['weather']['0']['description']
        var temperature = data['main']['temp']
        var wndspd = data['wind']['speed']
        var feelsLike = data['main']['feels_like']
        var weatherPic = data['weather']['icon']

        cityNameEl.innerHTML=`Weather of <span>${nameval}<span>`
        temperatureEL.innerHTML = `Temperature: <span>${convertion(temperature)} C</span>`
        feelsLikeEl.innerHTML = `Feels Like: <span>${feelsLike}<span>`
        descriptionEl.innerHTML = `Sky Conditions: <span>${descrip}<span>`
        windSpeedEl.innerHTML = `Wind Speed: <span>${wndspd} km/h<span>`
        weatherIconEl.innerHTML = {weatherPic}
    })
```

With this code I only get "Weather of" and "Feels Like:" working on my page. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: We need an example of what the `data` object looks like.

Comment: fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+citySearchEl.value+'&appid='+weatherApi)
        .then(res => res.json())

         //.then(data => console.log(data))

        .then(data => {

Comment: Edit your question with an example api response object.